# Shell - create zip files in directories without including subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, directory

I have a structure like this:

```
file1.jpg
file2.png
subfolder1
subfolder2
file3.jpg
...
```

now I would like to create a zip file via shell only of the files present in the root of the directory without taking into consideration the subdirectories and the files contained within them.

How can I do? I hope I have been clear enough

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this by using a find.
It will only find files that are in the current folder and zip it to a file called filename.zip

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec zip filename.zip '{}' \;`